# React SoundCloud API fetch items

Tags: reactjs

I trying to fetch the data and show the list of items

http://jsbin.com/puwigosoro/1/edit?js,console,output

I see the response, but nothing changes on the screen, what I doing wrong?
BTW, how can I debug what exists in state? console.log(this.state) shows nothing.

**Added:**
I found the problem but still didn't found the solution, *this* unknown inside callback of SC.get()

```
SC.get('/tracks', {
            q: query
            // license: 'cc-by-sa'
        }).then(function(tracks) {
            //console.log('this.state: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
            this.setState({search_results:tracks}); // THIS UNKNOWN HERE
        });
```

Comment: you arent passing in the searchInput into your         this.props.formSubmit(searchInput); log searchInput, its undefined...

Comment: console.log(searchInput); outputs the value if you input value in input field and press "Go", the problem is not here. As I wrote, I get the values as response. (SoundCloud key required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution, inner *this* of callback is overwrites our *this* so we just need to pass it to other variable:

```
_fetchResults(query){
var that = this; // <<<<<<<<<<< THIS LINE
SC.get('/tracks', {
    q: query
    // license: 'cc-by-sa'
}).then(function(search_results) {
    that.setState({search_results}, function () {
        console.log('callback of setState()');
    });
});
```

}